# Simple css class selector issue

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with a simple first of type css issue

I have

```
<div class='test'>
   <div>test 1</div>  
   <div>test 2</div>  

</div>

<div class='test'>
   <div>test 3</div>  
   <div>test 4</div>  
</div>

<div class='test'>
   <div>test 5</div>  
   <div>test 6</div>  
</div>
```

I want the first test div showing background red and the rest are blue.

I have

```
.test{
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 15px;
  border-top: dashed 1px grey;
}

.test:first-of-type{
  background-color: red;
  border-top:0;
}
```

but all my `divs` are showing blue. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Works for me. Have you double checked that you've correctly linked the CSS to the HTML file?

Comment: must be some browser issues. I will look into it. Thanks all! +1 all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as posted works, and [support to the `:first-of-type` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) is widespread. Perhaps you were testing on IE 8 or older? Or maybe on IE 9 but in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)? Alternatively, there might be some `div` before the `div` elements. If this does not help, please post a complete document and identify the browser(s) used for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy pasted the above scripts and its works fine here.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_first-of-type

Maybe some issue with the browser

Answer (score 1):

it works for me on ie9 and ff in fiddle.

My guess is you are using a browser that doesn't support css3. I'd suggest just putting another class on the first one so it's backwards compatible.

Here's it's compatibility:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstoftype